# Consume Spring login API(which redirect to Microsoft OIDC login URL) which return the final token in React (handle all redirections)

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I have scenario
-- a Spring Rest API (http\:localhost:9000\test\login) which redirect to Microsoft OIDC login UI and return token after successfully login
-- Next step, React UI hit Url http:\localhist:3000 which call the rest api(http\:localhost:9000\test\login), and then browser redirect to Microsoft OIDC OAuth code URL and pop up login window where we provide Azure AD credentials.
-- After successfully login, rest login api reciveve the token and other detail and return to react UI landing page

In this scenario, in browser multiple redirections are happeneing
UI -> Rest login -> Azure OIDC -> back to Rest login API -> back to UI

I am not sure how to handle this in React UI? please help with a sample code

I hava a rest api which redirect to OIDC login page, gets the token after login

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.